# How to make function call in foreach() using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I would like to know how to make function call in forEach() using javascript.

Below function works fine, but since in `doTransCalc` and `doFundCalc`, the calculations are similar, is there any alternative way to do this.

```js
var objFund = [{
  "sucess": "true",
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
}]

var objTrans = [{
  "sucess": "true",
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
}]


function doTransCalc(trans) {
  trans.forEach(e => {
    if (e.success) {
      e.rate = 2.0,
        e.netFee = e.fee + e.tax,
        e.amountwithfee = e.amount + e.netfee,
        e.total = e.amountwithfee * e.rate;
    }
  })
}

function doFundCalc(fund) {
  fund.forEach(e => {
    if (e.success) {
      e.rate = 4.0,
        e.addfee = 10,
        e.netFee = e.fee + e.tax,
        e.amountwithfee = e.amount + e.netfee,
        e.total = e.amountwithfee * e.rate;
    }
  })
}

doTransCalc(objTrans);
doFundCalc(objFund);

console.log(objTrans);
console.log(objFund);
```

Comment: Pass all different variables in as parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call a function from inside the `forEach` function with the proper parameters.

There were also some problems with your existing code:

- Your booleans were of the format `"true"` instead of `true`
- You had mispelled success in your jsons so you were retrieving a non existing property in `e.success`
- You had mixed camelcase and full lowercase names.

Please check the 3 following snippets:

```js
var objFund = [{
  "success": true,
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
}];

var objTrans = [{
  "success": true,
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
}];


function doTransCalc(trans) {
  trans.forEach(e => alterObject(e, 2));
  return trans;
}

function doFundCalc(fund) {
  fund.forEach(e => alterObject(e, 4, 10));
  return fund;
}

function alterObject(obj, rate, fee) {
  if (obj.success) {
    if (arguments.length > 2) obj.addfee = fee;
    obj.rate = rate;
    obj.netFee = obj.fee + obj.tax;
    obj.amountWithFee = obj.amount + obj.netFee;
    obj.total = obj.amountWithFee * obj.rate;
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(doTransCalc(objTrans));
console.log(doFundCalc(objFund));
```

You could also create the functions dynamically:

```js
var objFund = [{
  "success": true,
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
}];

var objTrans = [{
  "success": true,
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
}];

var doTransCalc = alterObject(2);
var doFundCalc = alterObject(4, 10);

function alterObject(rate, fee) {
  var params = arguments;
  return function(list) {
    list.forEach(obj => {
      if (obj.success) {
        if (params.length > 1) obj.addfee = fee;
        obj.rate = rate;
        obj.netFee = obj.fee + obj.tax;
        obj.amountWithFee = obj.amount + obj.netFee;
        obj.total = obj.amountWithFee * obj.rate;
        return obj;
      }
    });
    return list;
  };
}

console.log(doTransCalc(objTrans));
console.log(doFundCalc(objFund));
```

Finally, you could also take advantage of the [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) functions to set the `this` reference inside the other function:

```js
var objFund = [{
  "success": true,
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
}];

var objTrans = [{
  "success": true,
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
}];


function doTransCalc(trans) {
  trans.forEach(e => alterObject.call(e, 2));
  return trans;
}

function doFundCalc(fund) {
  fund.forEach(e => alterObject.call(e, 4, 10));
  return fund;
}

function alterObject(rate, fee) {
  if (this.success) {
    if (arguments.length > 2) this.addfee = fee;
    this.rate = rate;
    this.netFee = this.fee + this.tax;
    this.amountWithFee = this.amount + this.netFee;
    this.total = this.amountWithFee * this.rate;
  }
  return this;
}

console.log(doTransCalc(objTrans));
console.log(doFundCalc(objFund));
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I guess this will help you:

```
function doCalc(type, arr) {
    arr.forEach(e => {
        if (e.success) {
            e.rate = type === 'fund' ? 4.0 : 2.0,
            if(type === 'fund')
                e.addfee = 10;
            e.netFee = e.fee + e.tax,
            e.amountwithfee = e.amount + e.netfee,
            e.total = e.amountwithfee * e.rate;
        }
    })
}

doTransCalc('trans', objTrans);
doFundCalc('fund', objFund);
```

Comment: @Abinthaha thanks for reply, there are many key values that vary , but the keys `netfee, amountwithfee, total ` are the one similar,

Answer (score 0):

You can decompose the `forEach` call and common logic such as `if (e.success)` into a separate function:

```js
var objFund = [{
  "sucess": "true",
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
}];

var objTrans = [{
  "sucess": "true",
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
}];

function doCalc(fn) {
  return function (data) {
    data.forEach(e => {
      if (e.success) {
        fn(e)
      }
    })
  }
}

const doTransCalc = doCalc(e => {
    e.rate = 2.0,
    e.netFee = e.fee + e.tax,
    e.amountwithfee = e.amount + e.netfee,
    e.total = e.amountwithfee * e.rate;
});

const doFundCalc = doCalc(e => {
    e.rate = 4.0,
    e.addfee = 10,
    e.netFee = e.fee + e.tax,
    e.amountwithfee = e.amount + e.netfee,
    e.total = e.amountwithfee * e.rate;
});

doTransCalc(objTrans);
doFundCalc(objFund);

console.log(objTrans);
console.log(objFund);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one function and call your list with ES6 features.

```js
const fundList = [{
  "success": "true",
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
},
{
  "success": "true",
  "id": "fund",
  "options": "others",
  "fee": 3,
  "tax": 0.3,
  "amount": 2000
}]

const transList = [{
  "success": "true",
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
},
{
  "success": "true",
  "id": "trans",
  "options": "service",
  "fee": 2,
  "tax": 0.4,
  "amount": 1000
}]

function calc(e, rate, addFee) {
  const netFee = e.fee + e.tax;
  const amountwithfee = e.amount + netFee;
  return {
    rate: rate,
    addfee: addFee ? addFee : null,
    netFee,
    amountwithfee,
    total: amountwithfee * rate
  }
}
const newTransList = transList.filter(e => e.success === 'true').map(e => calc(e, 2));
console.log(newTransList);
const newFundList = fundList.filter(e => e.success === 'true').map(e => calc(e, 4, 10));
console.log(newFundList);
```